# get row from rich:datatable binding table

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I am using java 6 jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3
When I call the function getRowData on the Binded UIDataTable

```
public void priorityChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Task currentTask = (Task) table.getRowData();
```

with

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="id182_#{rkv}" value="#{dataItem.priority}"
    valueChangeListener="#{customerAdminHandler.priorityChanged}"
    onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{customerAdminHandler.priorityTypes}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

i get an exception on the  table.getRowData();

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.getRowData(ListDataModel.java:150)
    at org.ajax4jsf.model.SequenceDataModel.getRowData(SequenceDataModel.java:147)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getRowData(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:257)
```

Comment: The `<h:selectOneMenu>` is inside the datatable, right? Which datatable component exactly is it? The `<rich:dataTable>`, right?

Comment: yes its a rich:dataTable and my table is a UIDataTable ;

Comment: I'd bet it to be some bug in RichFaces side. It should work just fine with `<h:dataTable>`. Try queuing the value change event to `INVOKE_APPLICATION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed the problem by using

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dataItem}"
                            target="#{customerProductsHandler.currentApp}" />
```

instead of a binding table.
the same code worked for me on a clean environment so i guess there is some sort of jar problem.

anyway , for future reference I found the following information usefull for using a binding table

```
Richfaces 3.3 uses:
org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable

Richfaces 4  uses:
org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable

jsf1.2  uses:
javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;

jsf 2  uses:
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you binded your `rich:dataTable` to a component attribute of your managed bean? Plus, the type of the attribute must be `org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable`, at least this is how we achieved to select one row of the datatable (using the example code of @BalusC [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html)).

The jsp code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
        var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
        var el = radio.form.elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if(el[i].name != undefined) {
                if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                    el[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
        radio.checked = true;
    }
</script>
<!-- some html/jsp code -->
<rich:dataTable id="dtDocCartera" style="width:100%"
    binding="#{busquedaDocCartera.hdtCredito}"
    value="#{busquedaDocCartera.lstCredito}" var="credito" rows="15">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Select" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectOneRadio onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this)"
            valueChangeListener="#{busquedaDocCartera.setSelectedItem}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="null"/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column style="text-align:center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Some Data" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{credito.data}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

And this is our managed bean:

```
@KeepAlive(ajaxOnly=false)
public class PBusquedaDocCartera {
    private HtmlDataTable hdtCredito;
    private List<ECredito> lstCredito;
    //This will be the selected data
    private ECredito credito;
    //getters and setters for attributes...
    public void setSelectedItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        try {
            credito = (ECredito)hdtCredito.getRowData();
        } catch (Exception objEx) {
            //logging errors...
        }
    }
}
```